# Vanilla JavaScript - Syntax for adding class to element with specific data attr

Tags: javascript

Trying to add a class to an element with a specific data attribute.

The element is: `<a data-type="foo">Linkypoo</a>`

I am trying to target like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="foo"]').classList.add('Booya');
```

but I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Could someone point me in the right direction. Not sure how to do this with vanilla js.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns an Element-Collection, to access the first element use `querySelectorAll(...)[0]`

If you want to apply it to all Elements you can loop through them like in the Example below:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="foo"]')

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].classList.add('Booya');
}
```

```css
.Booya {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a data-type="foo">Linkypoo 1</a>
<a data-type="foo">Linkypoo 2</a>
<a data-type="foo">Linkypoo 3</a>
<a data-type="foo">Linkypoo 4</a>
```

Comment: if you want just one element, use `querySelector()` imo, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Wonderful - thank you :) Why is the [0] needed? To prevent just a nodelist getting returned? Would this add the class to all elements if there were more than one with this data attr?

Comment: If there is more then one in the list you whill have to go through all Elements of the list. Do you want me to add an example?

Comment: If you don't mind, that would be fantastic. Appreciate the help:)

Comment: @LeMoi too late, already added it :D

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you :)